# Add a plotly figure as an inset to another plotly figure

Tags: r, plotly, insets

I think this is a plotting situation that probably commonly occurs in data science.

I have some data on which I'm conducting a statistical test and I want to plot the data together with the outcomes of the statistical test in a single plot.

Here's an example:

The data are two distributions (from two groups):

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

data.df <- data.frame(val = c(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,1,1)),
                 group = c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100)))
```

I graph these data using a density plot:

```
density.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(levels(data.df$group),function(g){
  dens <- density(dplyr::filter(data.df,group == g)$val)
  data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y, group = g)
}))

library(plotly)

density.plot <- plot_ly(x = density.df$x, y = density.df$y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',color = density.df$group) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title= "Value", zeroline = F), yaxis = list(title = "Density", zeroline = F))
```

Which gives:
[image]

And let's assume I fitted some statistical model to them, with two factors of interest, and obtained these results:

```
effects.df <- data.frame(effect = c(0.5, 0.75), effect.error = c(0.05,0.1), factor = c("Factor-A","Factor-B"))
```

I graph these data in what's known as a caterpillar plot:

```
effects.plot <- plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = "markers", marker = list(size = 13, color = "black"),
                        x = effects.df$effect, y = effects.df$factor, showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(range=c(-1,1), title = "Effect Size", zeroline = T, showticklabels = T, font = list(size=15)),
         yaxis = list(title = NA, zeroline = F, showticklabels = T, tickvals = effects.df$factor, ticktext = as.character(effects.df$factor)), font = list(size = 15)) %>%
  add_trace(error_x = list(array = effects.df$effect.error, width = 5, color = "black"), showlegend = F)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Now I would like to add `effects.plot` as an inset to the top right quadrant of `density.plot`. I'm specific about adding it as an inset rather than grouping them using `plotly`'s `subplot` function.

So my question is how do I do this?

`plotly` does have an [example](https://plot.ly/r/insets/) of adding insets but my attempts to fit my case into that have failed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a new couple of axes (`xaxis2` and `yaxis2`) using `layout` and then to refer the second plot to this coordinate system.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
data.df <- data.frame(val = c(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,1,1)),
                 group = c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100)))

density.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(levels(data.df$group),
     function(g) {
      dens <- density(dplyr::filter(data.df,group == g)$val)
      data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y, group = g)
     }) )

effects.df <- data.frame(effect = c(0.5, 0.75), 
                         effect.error = c(0.05,0.1), 
                         factor = c("Factor-A","Factor-B"))

density.plot <- density.df %>%
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~group,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
add_markers(x = ~effect, y = ~factor, showlegend = F, 
            error_x=list(array=~effect.error, width=5, color="black"),
            marker = list(size = 13, color = "black"), 
            xaxis = 'x2', yaxis = 'y2', data=effects.df, inherit=F) %>%
layout(xaxis = list(title= "Value", zeroline = F), 
       yaxis = list(title = "Density", zeroline = F),
       xaxis2 = list(domain = c(0.7, 0.95), anchor='y2', range=c(-1,1), title = "Effect Size", 
                     zeroline = T, showticklabels = T, font = list(size=15)),
       yaxis2 = list(domain = c(0.5, 0.95), anchor='x2', title = NA, zeroline = F, 
                     showticklabels = T, tickvals = effects.df$factor, 
                     ticktext = as.character(effects.df$factor)))
```

[image]